# Table layout for itemview in a list view android performance

Tags: android, performance, listview, tableview

I am trying to develop a facebook kind of feeds using list view and table view. Each row has the feed post with comments in the list view. I am storing the data objects of feed in the array list.

```
class FeedPost{
   String username;
   String imageUrl;
   String feedpostText;
   ArrayList<Comment> comments;}
```

In my get view i am doing like this

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    feedItem = FeedItems.get(position);

   convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_main, null);
   TableLayout mainFeedLayout = (TableLayout) convertView
      .findViewById(R.id.blogFeedTableLayout);

   TextView displayName = (TextView) convertView
               .findViewById(R.id.feed_username);
   TextView description = (TextView) convertView
                     .findViewById(R.id.comment_text);

    // Set the text to the texview
       .
       .
       .

    // Adding comments to the feed
   for (int i = 0; i < feedItem.feedComments.size(); i++) {
       mainFeedLayout .addView(addComment(
      convertView, feedItem.feedComments.get(i)));
     }

    }
```

Again in addcomments functions i am inflating the comment layout so that it can be added to the table layout

So for a single feed to be displayed in the list view, I am checking the each feed item for comments and displaying them in the feed. This is really painful and slow.

I tried using the static holders for layouts instead of inflating them each time. Again that didnt work also. If there are mulitple different views, then i would have tried "SackOfViewsAdapter " of commonsguy. But actually it is not different views.

I think facebook uses the webview and render the html for the showing the feeds of the user. What is the best way to do the same using the android native layout and code. Can you help me in suggesting the best method to use for showing this kind of complex data?

Comment: Recycling views should be faster anyway, right? I extended the class as ArrayAddapter<Object> and recycled the views as much as I could.

Comment: Since the table layout varies based on the content, recycling is hard. Please consider the facebook feedview, It is not easy to recycle the views i believe, since comment for each feed will vary according to the post. any suggestions?

Comment: You're incorrect, you can recycle a lot. Now you have to instantiate the TextViews for every list item. If you recycle, then you only have to set the text for every list item. Please read some more about recycling and see for yourself how it works during debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my implementation. I removed a lot of views, just wanted to show how a remote image view (from Ignition / Droid-fu) could be recycled.

```
public class DealAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DealObject> {

private Context mContext;
private Activity mActivity;
private ArrayList<DealObject> mItems;
private int mXmlId;

public DealAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<DealObject> items, Activity activity) {
super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
this.mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
this.mActivity = activity;
this.mItems = items;
this.mXmlId = textViewResourceId;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//View v = null;
View v = convertView;
ViewHolder holder = null;
RemoteImageLoader imageLoader = new RemoteImageLoader(mContext, true);
RemoteImageView dealImage = null;

DealObject mo = mItems.get(position); 
try { 
    if (v == null) { 
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(mXmlId, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        dealImage = (RemoteImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.deal_image);

        holder.dealImage = dealImage;
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the ImageView.
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.dealImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        dealImage = holder.dealImage;
    }

    if(mo.getImage() != null){ 
        // calling reset is important to prevent old images from displaying in a recycled view.
        dealImage.reset();
        holder.dealImage.setImageUrl(imageUrl);
        try {
            holder.dealImage.loadImage();
        }
            catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }  
}
catch (Exception ex) { 
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
    return v; 
} 

private static final class ViewHolder {
    private RemoteImageView dealImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things: Re use views and make an Asynctask to load the feed (Move the feed and the for to the task). That way you won't choke the UI thread.

I order to re use the views its easy. Something like this:

```
if (convertView == null) {
            row = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.account, parent, false);
            } else {
            row = (LinearLayout) convertView;
            }
```

For the asynctask, I would pass the view that you want to update to the asynctask and let the task update the view when is done.

Comment: Recycling view is not possible since, the comments in the table view get changing. A blog feed can have 1 or more comments. If I recycle the view, I am able to see all the comments and views that are mismatching. Can you please explain me in detail of recycling?

Comment: When you scroll, the view gets updated several times, even if you dont update the information. Try debugging and you will see it calls the getView several times.